# Suggested order for the "Legends of the Dragonrealm" series?

Tags: suggested-order, legends-of-dragonrealm

I have looked all over the internet, and have not been able to find an answer.

What is the reading order (by date released) for Richard A. Knaak's "[Legends of the Dragonrealm](http://www.richardaknaak.com/the_dragonrealm.html)" books (including novellas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the author's [own Facebook page](https://m.facebook.com/TheDragonrealm/posts/1395665214072154), his suggested reading order is;

> LEGENDS OF THE DRAGONREALM
>   LEGENDS OF THE DRAGONREALM VOL. II
>   LEGENDS OF THE DRAGONREALM VOL III
>   LEGENDS OF THE DRAGONREALM VOL. IV
>   SHADE
>   THE TURNING WAR TRILOGY (can be read alongside any of the omnibuses
>   THE DRAGON THRONE TRILOGY
>
> Or, if you have all the individual novels:
>
> FIREDRAKE
>   ICE DRAGON
>   WOLFHELM
>   SHADOW STEED
>   THE SHROUDED REALM
>   CHILDREN OF THE DRAKE
>   DRAGON TOME
>   THE CRYSTAL DRAGON
>   THE DRAGON CROWN
>   THE HORSE KING
>   (All previous novellas save GAME OF GHOSTS)
>   SHADE
>   DRAGON MASTERS
>   THE GRYPHON MAGE

---

If you're solely interested in the *original publishing order*, then Goodreads is your friend ([1](http://www.goodreads.com/series/53043-legends-of-the-dragonrealm), [2](http://www.goodreads.com/series/53041-dragonrealm), [3](http://www.goodreads.com/series/53042-dragonrealm-origins))